# 12 volt source from AA

Tags: voltage

so earlier I posted a question about using two 9 volts and dropping them to 12 volts. now that I know this is a poor choice for what I am after, I am curious to know if there is anything I can buy that hooks doube A batteries up in a circuit with one positive and one negative wire coming from it. im sure there is an item out there that does this, I just cannot figure out what to search for to find it. . . some help?

Comment: Guys, don't downvote new member so hard, this will ban him forever.

Answer (score 2):

"8 aa holder"

[image]

[image]

And on and on and on...

Answer (score 0):

So you want 12V from AA batteries?

Well, you can just place 8 of them end-to-end to give you 12V directly (you may need 10 if you use NiMH since they are ~1.2V not 1.5V).

If you want it smaller, and more "electronic", then you need a "boost converter".  This is like a switching power supply, except it raises the voltage instead of lowering it.